# Is it safe to return a VLA?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, dynamic-arrays

The following code uses the heap:

```
char* getResult(int length) {
    char* result = new char[length];
    // Fill result...
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    char* result = getResult(100);
    // Do something...
    delete result;
}
```

So `result` has to be deleted somewhere, preferably by the owner.

The code below, from what I understand, use an extension called VLA, which is part of C99, and not part of the C++ standard (but supported by GCC, and other compilers):

```
char* getResult(int length) {
    char result[length];
    // Fill result...
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    char* result = getResult(100);
    // Do something...
}
```

Am I correct in assuming that `result` is still allocated on the stack in this case?

Is `result` a copy, or is it a reference to garbage memory? Is the above code safe?

Comment: The VLA is a red herring. You're returning the address of a variable that's going out of scope, period.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't want to be picky but scope and lifetime are different concepts. When you call a function, a variable declared at block scope also goes out of scope, but its lifetime does not end.

Comment: @ouah: Yeah, true: "A variable whose lifetime is ending as it's going out of scope", I should have said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I correct in assuming that result is still allocated on the stack in this case?

Correct. VLA have automatic storage duration.

> Is result a copy, or is it a reference to garbage memory? Is the above code safe?

The code is not safe. The address returned by `getResult` is an invalid address. Dereferencing the pointer invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour VLA in GNU C and in GNU C++ have the same behavior as  in C99.

Answer (score 5):

You can not return it, in *C* it will have automatic storage duration(*the object will not be valid once you leave the scope*) and returning it will invoke [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), from the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.2.4` *Storage durations of objects* paragraph *6*:

> For such an object that does have a variable length array type, its **lifetime extends from the declaration of the object until execution of the program leaves the scope** of the
>   declaration.27) If the scope is entered recursively, a new instance of the object is created each time. The initial value of the object is indeterminate.

In *C++* we have to rely on the docs since it is extension in that case and the [gcc docs on VLA](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) says that it is deallocated when the scope ends:

> These arrays are declared like any other automatic arrays, but with a length that is not a constant expression. The storage is allocated at the point of declaration and deallocated when the block scope containing the declaration exits.

Answer (score 1):

When you return from `getResult()`, the char array `result` will go out of scope and be deallocated along with the stack frame for the function call. If you want to preserve the function structure, you'll have to call `malloc` and later free the memory.

Comment: “Scope” is the wrong term; the “lifetime” of the array `result` ends when the function returns. Identifiers have scope. Objects have lifetimes. Objects may be accessible even when their identifiers are out of scope, as when a pointer to an object is properly passed to a routine that cannot see its declaration.