# Can't I return a list initialization directly in C++?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

```
struct vec2{float x,y;};
```

This will work:

```
vec2* window(float h, float w)
{
    vec2 ret[4] = {{w,h},{1-w,h},{1-w,1-h},{w,1-h}};
    return ret;
}
```

But this won't:

```
vec2* window(float h, float w)
{
    return {{w,h},{1-w,h},{1-w,1-h},{w,1-h}};
}
```

I guess the error comes from the fact that the latter doesn't specify the size of the array, but I don't know if I'm missing something...

I also tried:

```
return vec2[4]({{w,h},{1-w,h},{1-w,1-h},{w,1-h}});
```

Comment: Very similar to [Is it safe to return a VLA?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18771165/1708801)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return an array by value, and you mustn't return a pointer to an automatic or temporary object, since it will be destroyed when the function returns, leaving the pointer invalid.

Return `std::array` if the size is a known, small constant or `std::vector` otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

> This will work:

No, it won't. You're returning a pointer to a local array. The pointer immediately becomes invalid.

Pointers are not arrays. This is also one of the reasons that your initialisation is failing: there is literally no way for the compiler to know that this:

```
vec2* ptr = {{w,h},{1-w,h},{1-w,1-h},{w,1-h}};
```

is meant to be this:

```
vec2 ret[4] = {{w,h},{1-w,h},{1-w,1-h},{w,1-h}};
vec2* ptr = ret;
```

The initialisation in the latter only works because the compiler knows it's a `vec2[4]` that you are initialising.

You should entirely rethink this, possibly returning a `std::array<vec2, 4>`. By value.